# Como hacer una list de un objeto y guardarlo en un txt, separado por tabulaciones y saltar la linea en el ultimo campo

Tags: c#, lista

```
$ using System;
//Se incluya la libreria de entrada / salida
//Para poder utilizar las clases de lectura / escritura
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using objeto;
using Archivos_Ejemplo1;

namespace Archivos_Ejemplo1
{
    class Program
    {
        static StreamReader Leer;
        static StreamWriter Escribir;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Title = "ejemplo en C#";
        int Op;
        string Cadena;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite 1 para crear y escribir sobre un archivo.");
        Console.WriteLine("Digite 2 para leer un archivo.");
        Op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Op == 1)
        {
            //------------ Creacion de lista de objeto --------------
            objeto s = new objeto();
            List<objeto> xa = new List<objeto>();
            // --------------------------------------------------   
            foreach (objeto item in xa)
            {

            }
                Escribir = new StreamWriter("Archivo.txt", true);
                Console.WriteLine("insertar");
                Cadena = (Console.ReadLine());
                Escribir.Write(Cadena + "\t");
                Console.WriteLine("Escritura exitosa...");
        }
        if (Op == 2)
        {
            Leer = new StreamReader("Archivo.txt", true);
            Cadena = Leer.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\tLo leido del archivo es: " + Cadena);
            Leer.Close();
        }
        Escribir.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Buenas quiero hacer una list de un objeto, y cada propiedad separarla por una tabulacion(ya eso esto) pero cuando llegue al ultimo campo hago un salto de linea. No he logrado descifrar como hacerlo. Es en C#

Comment: Hola @JesusBauza, más que escribir un comentario deberías haber explicado tu problema en el cuerpo de la pregunta (justo antes del código), que está precisamente para eso :-)

Comment: Te recomiendo esta libreria/componente nuget [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/) el [componente nuget aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una libreria que se llama [LinqToCSV](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library), el cual permite exportar a un archivo separado por un separador configurable, esta libreria esta disponible por nuget. En terminos generales, lo que se requiere por ejemplo, si cada objeto en `xa` es una linea, por `reflection` obtener los valores de las propiedades, al final del ciclo insertar un salto de linea, le recomiendo usar `Escribir.Write(System.Environment.NewLine)`, esto en el caso que no sea la ultima linea de la lista.